# Bind one process to multiple ports?

Tags: debian, process, fork

I have a socket server running and listening for incoming connections on a non-admin port (i.e. > 1024). I would also like for this process to be able to handle another type of connection on a different port for monitoring purposes. I have found questions on SE for the opposite situation, many-to-one but this would be a one-to-many situation.

My questions: Is it possible to bind one process to multiple ports?

If so can I reliably handle connections on the different ports uniquely (i.e. port 2000 execute one piece of code and port 3000 execute another).

I am open to other suggestions as to how to handle a connection to monitor the other clients that are that are connecting to the primary port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely possible You can use a selector or poll to receive notifications and manage each connection.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a programming question, but for a program you have not written yet, and in an unspecified language.

> Is it possible to bind one process to multiple ports?

Yes.

> can I reliably handle connections on the different ports uniquely

Yes, each listening (bound) port is serviced by a separate socket (as are all the connections made from each listening port).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to see if there were any reasons this wouldn't work before I begin to implement it in the application. I was trying to keep the question language agnostic.